# explanation of result of function auto.arima()

Tags: time-series

I used the function auto.arima() to a monthly data but I obtained "ARIMA(0,1,0)". 
any explanation of this result ?

Comment: It means the model is not AR and not MA but I(1), i.e. a random walk

Comment: Yes, that will be the model for your data, and you can look up the structure of the ARIMA. Here you go. https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/49

Comment: Please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ARIMA+explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The model is a first-difference model used to handle non-stationarity. When $X_i$ is the $i$th observation in the series, the model is $Y_i = X_i - X_{i-1}$.